# How to change logo on search result page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, search-results

Looks like I'm unable to set site logo on the search result page through applying custom master page referencing a css. Looks like there is inline css on this page.
Also the welcome content type using Search People page layout, it has the same issue.
Here is my Design Manager SiteLogo snippet:

```
        <div data-name="SiteLogo">
                                <!--CS: Start Site Logo Snippet-->
                                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                                <!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" BlockElement="True">-->
                                    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                                    <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink runat="server" CssClass="" ID="x4ceadb20ece54c0d8c023aed9db14508" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection">-->
                                        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                                        <!--MS:<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" runat="server" CssClass="" ID="x80aae98142e54113bd0e73cdb3cfccba" LogoImageUrl="/_catalogs/masterpage/mycompany/images/dentonsLogonew.jpg">-->
                                        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><img id="ctl00_x80aae98142e54113bd0e73cdb3cfccba" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" Src="http://portal.mycompany.com/_catalogs/masterpage/mycompany/images/MyCompanyLogo.jpg" alt="My Company Intranet" /><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                                        <!--ME:</SharePoint:SiteLogoImage>-->
                                        <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                                    <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>-->
                                    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
                                <!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
                                <!--CE: End Site Logo Snippet-->
                                <!--CE: End Site Logo Snippet-->
                            </div>
```

Comment: Is it not applying the custom masterpage? Or is it applying the custom masterpage and not using the logo you specified? Or, last question, is the search results page layout possibly hiding the header area?

Comment: yes, its not applying the logo. It does apply to all the other pages. except the search result page. is there a way to override the inline css and apply my own site logo?

Comment: Which site template are you using? Basic Search or Enterprise Search?

Comment: ok I'm talking about Welcome Page Content Type, used the search result page layout. This is regular publishing site with my custom master page which was modified of Seattle master page.

Comment: Apart from that the search centre is based of the enterprise search template, it has also the same issue. I applied my custom master page and the logo does not change.

Comment: http://sympmarc.com/2014/12/26/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365-part-2-set-up-an-employee-directory-page/

Comment: OK, a few more questions: Have you tried changing the LogoImageUrl to a full url rather than a relative url? Does that page display the default SharePoint logo or a broken image icon or no logo at all?

Comment: Yes, tried that full url as well. All the other pages the logo changes. It displays the SharePoint logo.

Answer (score 0):

My account couldn't comment yet but I assume this is a search center. Have you "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting" and "Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL" ?